# How to Show Video and Images in the Same View Using Typscript

Tags: image, ionic-framework, video

I am trying to Create a List in Ionic where i have a common array for videos and image url's

```
body = [{media: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gymtest-ed199.appspot.com/o/uploads%2Fg2VZAx27ABOBG7fpo7LyRiIIe8c2%2F20190527_163701.mp4?alt=media&token=0ce4a8d2-3334-49de-99a7-24724e986f80"},
              {media:"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gymtest-ed199.appspot.com/o/uploads%2FgtNphS09UEQKFbzTzPn9CdZyKyM2%2F1558535656752.jpg?alt=media&token=5885af85-d5c9-43e5-a852-b974ce5b49ba"}]
```

The first Url is Video and the Second Url is Image

Here is my HTML:-

```
<ion-item *ngFor= "let d of body">
  <video height="150px" width="300px" controls="controls" preload="metadata" autoplay="autoplay" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" class="videoPlayer">
   <source [src]="d.media" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
  <ion-thumbnail>
   <img [src]="d.media"/> 
  </ion-thumbnail>
</ion-item>
```

I want to implement *ngIf to determine if the url is .mp4, load to video tag and if url is .jpg, load to img tag

P.S I am a rookie in ionic..

Answer (score 0):

modify your array’s elements to have content type property:

```
body = [
    { media: yourVideoUrlHere, type: “video” },
    { media: yourImageUrlHere, type: “image” },
]
```

Then in your template for videos add structural directive:

```
*ngIf=“d.type==‘video’”
```

For images:

```
*ngIf=“d.type==‘image’”
```